# XML десериализация

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь выполнить десериализацию XML документа, но почему то получается выбрать, только первый элемент из XML.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlClass));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"F:\XML1.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlClass newPerson = (XmlClass)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
            Console.WriteLine("Объект десериализован");
            foreach (var o in newPerson.Info.Man)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Значение: {0} ", o.info);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс в который передаю элементы:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = ("Document"))]
public class XmlClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Personal")]
    public InfoClass Info { get; set; }
}
public class InfoClass 
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Work")]
    public List<ManClass> Man { get; set; }

}
public class ManClass
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "info")]
    public string info { get; set; }
}
```

Пример XML-документа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
    <Personal>
        <Work info="Работающий">
            <users  info="1">
                <user name="Bill Gates">
                <company>Microsoft</company>
                <age>48</age>
            </user  info="2">
                <user name="Larry Page">
                <company>Google</company>
                <age>42</age>
            </user>
            </users>
        </Work>     
    </Personal> 
</Document>
```

Comment: Приведите пример XML.

Comment: @Tibomso: А XML? Что-то не верю, что у вас так XML-тэг `<Главный элемент>`.

Comment: Кажется я понял в чем ошибся, я хотел выбрать атрибут "info" из элемента "users" , а получилось так, что я заполнил коллекцию атрибутом "info" из элемента "work", только теперь вопрос, как мне заполнить коллекцию атрибутами элемента "users"... (:

Comment: Всё получилось, но если у Вас есть варианты я бы хотел на них посмотреть, потому что думаю я не совсем правильно сделал (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pavel Mayorov да, я так и сделал, но спасибо за совет! (:

Десереализация:

```
var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentClass));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"F:\XML2.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var newPerson = (DocumentClass)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
            Console.WriteLine("Объект десериализован");
            foreach (Users o in newPerson.Personal.work.users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0}", o.user[0].name);
                Console.WriteLine("Значение: {0} {1}", o.user[0].company, o.user[0].age);
                Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0}", o.user[1].name);
                Console.WriteLine("Значение: {0} {1}", o.user[1].company, o.user[1].age);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Класс:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = ("Document"))]
public class DocumentClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Personal")]
    public Personal Personal { get; set; }
}
public class Personal
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Work")]
    public Work work { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "info")]
    public string info { get; set; }
}
public class Work
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "users")]
    public List<Users> users { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "info")]
    public string info { get; set; }
}
public class Users
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "info")]
    public string info { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "user")]
    public List<User> user { get; set; }       
}
public class User
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "company")]
    public string company { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "age")]
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас класс `ManClass` соответствует тэгу `<Work>` - а, по названию, должен соответствовать `<users>` или `<user>`.

Добавьте еще несколько уровней классов.